# Firing didEndOnExit programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I have many textfields created in my application, and i want them to close keyboard when user finishes editing. I know that if textField's created by IB, and there is an IBAction i can use but what if the textField's created like this,

```
int top = 60;
for(NSUInteger i=0; i< [kArray count]; i++){
        UITextField *kField = [kArray objectAtIndex:i];
        kField.frame = CGRectMake(130, top, 60, 30);
        kField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        kField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        kField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        kField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;

        [scrollView addSubview:kField];
        top += 50;
    }
```

How can i close the keyboard when user presses done button?

Answer (score 2):

Use UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
#pragma mark UITextFieldDelegate methods

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Remember to make your class comply with delegate like so:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Comment: Don't forget to assign your view controller as the delegate of `kField`. `kField.delegate = self`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *)textField {
    [kField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```